# Как устроен объектный файл `elf` в Linux?

Tags: elf, linux

Как устроен объектный файл `elf` в Linux?

Comment: ELF — это сокращение от Executable and Linkable Format (формат исполняемых и связываемых файлов) и определяет структуру бинарных файлов, библиотек, и файлов ядра (core files). Спецификация формата позволяет операционной системе корректно интерпретировать содержащиеся в файле машинные команды. Файл ELF, как правило, является выходным файлом компилятора или линкера и имеет двоичный формат. С помощью подходящих инструментов он может быть проанализирован и изучен.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. вопрос слишком общий. Полноценным ответом будет пересказ спецификации формата, либо выдержки из нее (например, копипаста из википедии), в любом случае ответ получится слишком объемным.

Answer (score 4):

Объектный файл состоит из

1. заголовка файла, содержащего карту файла
2. таблицы заголовков программ
3. набора сегментов, содержащего информацию необходимую для сборки программы
4. набора секций, содержащего информацию необходимую для выполнения программы
5. таблицы заголовков секций

Файлы, используемые для выполнения программ должны содержать таблицу заголовков программ, а файлы, используемые для сборки должны содержать таблицу заголовков секций. Порядок сегментов и секций может быть любым.

Comment: @Danis и какой смысл был в этой правке? Все равно нумерация с точкой отображается.

Comment: @insolor в начале посмотрел показалось что нумерации небыло, потом поправил и понял что все было нормально